# How to trigger didReceiveRemoteNotification in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The following function is triggered whenever a silent notification is sent from my server:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("Received Silent Notification")

}
```

However this function is only triggered while the app is visible on the screen (aka in the foreground). If I tap on the home button and then send the silent notification from my server, nothing is triggered on my sandbox device.

I am building an email verification system upon user registration and server polling will not work at scale.

This is what my Info.plist looks like:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Is this a sandbox bug? How can I get the above function to be triggered when the app is in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`

The system calls this method when the app is running in the foreground or background. While the delegate method you are using is called only when the app is running in the foreground.

Comment: Actually, adding completionHandler(.newData) fixed it for some reason. Thanks